# One mouse over Paragraph change in Article

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I wanted to have a feature in my Jommla based application, that when ever a user brings the mouse over a particular paragraph in article the color of text should change. so that the paragraph looks more prominent on the screen.

I want this thing to be dynamic. Just wanted to know which is the best place to do that. Where in the Joomla the article parsing takes place ?. If I am lucky is there any plugin that can help achieve that ? Kindly let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a slight modification to Trev's solution and make it work without having to change any articles.

```
.contentpaneopen p:hover {color:#ff0000;}
```

By default, Joomla assigns the contentpaneopen class to articles, this would produce the effect on all P tags that are children of that class.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest thing to do would be to add a style to paragraph in question in your article and then add an appropriate hover rule in the css, e.g.

```
<p class="highlight>some text in here</p>
```

and

```
p.highlight:hover
{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Just tried it here and it worked for me on the last paragraph:

http://thelunarscape.com/blog/an-increasingly-active-sun

Better solution than using a plugin in this case, unless you want to something more fancy I guess as content plugins are run every time an article is loaded no matter if it's needed or not.

Comment: Some older versions of IE (definitely 6, not sure about 7 or 8) don't support :hover for anything other than the 'a' tag so you need to use javascript if you intend to support them. But really, don't bother supporting them unless you absolutely have to for some reason.

Comment: that may not be the right choice for me as I have too many articles on the website..and going to the article level and making these changes would be very difficult to maintain. I need something more dynamic and out of box

Answer (score 0):

Another more advanced way to achieve this is with help of MooTools.

Include MooTools with in your application with:

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.html.behavior' );
JHtml::_('behavior.framework'); //MooTools core
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true); //This is for MooTools more libraries
```

Next create a script that changes the css of the paragraph with id "myid":

```
    $js = <<<EOD
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('myid').setStyle( 'border', '1px solid #000000')
    });
    EOD;
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Why use MooTools?
MooTools makes it possible to tweak the highlightning and even animate the highlight. It should also have better support for the older browsers.

Comment: Note that this will also work in a template override, if you don't want to change the source of the application / component.